# What should be order of reading Hindu scriptures and texts for understanding Soul, God, Karm, Moksha and purpose of creation?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, upanishads, atma

I do want to understand fundamental concepts like Soul, God, Karm, Moksh and of course purpose of this life or creation that include everything at more deeper and detailed level.

I guess main sources are [Hindu scriptures and texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_texts) like [Vedas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas), [Upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upanishad), [Puranas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas) and more.

I already have read [Bhagavad Gita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita) and 4 cantos of [Bhagavata Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavata_Purana)

These are many books. So what should be proper order to read them?

Answer (score 1):

Bhagavad Gita is that one book which speaks about it all. Lord Krishna explains it all in the Bhagvad Gita. Gita is the compilation of all the Vedic scriptures. So instead of reading many books read Gita would be my suggestion.

Comment: I have read Bhagavad Gita, its a good book but I need more detail.